# How to take credit card payments from user in iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone

I am new to credit card payment applications, I am developing an iPhone application which requires to take credit card payments from the user. In this application I am just providing a coupon to the user and if the user uses the coupon I just want to collect $1 from the user's credit card.

I have read In App Purchase guide but this doesn't suit for this requirement it seems since my coupons are just builtin-App products.

can anyone provide other method which best suits for my requirement or if IAPP suits for my requirement, how to approach.

some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you are planning to distribute your app.  Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) it will reject almost any app that takes payments via anything other than in-App purchase.  There may be some narrow exceptions, but you should take a very careful look at part 11 of their approval guidelines (from the link).

Comment: As I said he should just accept payments via his Web Service which he could implement through an WebView into his App. Apple just can't reject such an App, because you pay through an website not an App.

Comment: Just to clarify, for non-digital/physical goods you could implement your own card-payment mechanism. But for things to be used in the app - which is what yours sounds like, you will have to use in-app purchasing via Apple.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to implement in App purchase for every coupon and the in app purchase just unlocks the content(which must be stored in the application or downloaded from your server).
super easy.
But I would recommend you to implement a feature like buying credits for the app.
You can create an in App Purchase for let's say one (1$) 3, 3$) and so on. This can be send to your server(of course you need to make the billing management on your own) and the iPhone User can identify himself by an User Name and an Password to get access o their Credits and redeem them instantly in the App. In this Situation you could even extend your service by adding PayPal Payment(in an WebView inside the Application).

I Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to distribute my app through AppStore only. "Woodleader" please give me more details on what you mentioned in above reply.  Please bear with me since I am new to In App Purchase applications.

Comment: Currently I haven't much time to explain but you should read the PDF from apple about in app purchase. I think it explains it very well. http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf